# kotlin how to overwrite const in test

Tags: unit-testing, kotlin, timer, constants

just throwing this out there, hoping there is a clean answer other than the obvious sub par answer.

I have a class that will trigger after a set period of time which is defined in a const. In my test i want that time to be smaller so the test runs faster. Is there a way to override a const in a test?

The current ugly solution is i am changing the code so that the delay time is passed through as a parameter, which is ugly as this parameter will only get used in the test.

```
const val DELAY_BEFORE_CODE_MILLIS: Long = 300000

class CheckValues(
    private val vertx: Vertx
) {
   
    fun doStuff() {
        vertx.setTimer(DELAY_BEFORE_AGGREGATION_CHECK_MILLIS) {
            <code i want to test>
    }

    ...

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution would be to pass the delay time in the `doStuff()` function. You could have `DELAY_BEFORE_AGGREGATION_CHECK_MILLIS` as a default parameter so the callers don't have to pass the delay time every time

```
    fun doStuff(delayMillis: Long = DELAY_BEFORE_AGGREGATION_CHECK_MILLIS) {
        vertx.setTimer(delayMillis) {
            <code i want to test>
    }
```

In your tests you can pass whichever delay you would like to.

This is a general rule of thumb for cleaner code and testing. Instead of creating the dependencies internally in a class or function, you pass them as constructor or function parameters.

Comment: That is literally what i said is my current ugly solution...

It is ugly as i am changing production code to be less encapsulated and more complex purely for the sake of making it more testable.

Comment: I don't think it is ugly to pass delay as a parameter. 
I don't know exactly what you would like to test and how (since there is no visible output in `doStuff()`). 
A possibility is, assuming you don't test the `Vertx` object, that you pass a mock Vertx in CheckValues() and mock `setTimer()`